# gitKraken throw "failed to retrieve list of ssh authentication methods error waiting on socket"

Tags: git, gitkraken

I use gitKraken and I get an error when I'm trying to pull from master.

"failed to retrieve list of ssh authentication methods error waiting on socket"

I tried to generate a new ssh key and put it in my bitBucket repository but it didn't help.

- I can't use the integration feature in gitKraken.

Any help will be great,
Thanks.

Comment: This occurs occasionally. Restarting GitKraken works in my case. You can also inspect your ports by process from the terminal and kill anything from GitKraken that may be holding onto a port (this is after shutting down GitKraken)

Comment: same here, push works in terminal. Just restart GitKraken.

Comment: Same for me... Had to restart GUI... Seemed my Gitkraken performed an update silently

Comment: In my case gitkraken restart doesn't help always.

Comment: You also hit CMD/CTRL-R to refresh GitKraken (It's an Electron app, so it's basically a HTML app)

Answer (score 6):

This looks like some occasional issue that doesn't cause by a consistent issue. In my case, restarting the GitKraken works.

Comment: Me too, just restart Gitkraken.